# Angular 2 routing issue

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am using dropwizard for my back end services and angular 2 for my webapp.

I am currently facing an issue with angular routing while trying to bring up the details page. 
I am able to bring up the main page (which is the MasterComponent page). 
From the MasterComponent page, the user can click onto a row that will invoke the DetailsComponent page. When I click on the row to go the the details I get a HTTP 404 for this issue .

**I am not clear how the angular URL should look so that it is able to invoke the details page?**

**HTTP Error I get**

```
GET http://localhost:8199/detail 404 (Not Found)
```

In my dropwizard application I am serving the static assets as below

```
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/static", "/dashboard", "index.html", "static-assets"));
```

These are my angular routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'master', component: MasterComponent},
  {path: 'detail', component: DetailComponent}
  ];
```

From my master component, I specify the below to navigate to the details page

```
onRowClick(event) {
    window.open('./detail','_self' );
  }
```

Below is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Web</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<dashboard-app></dashboard-app>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dashboard/inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dashboard/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dashboard/styles.bundle.js">/script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dashboard/vendor.bundle.js">/script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dashboard/main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my angular-cli.json file I specified the `deployUrl": "dashboard/"` attribute that maps the path in  index.html when I run ng build command.

Comment: i guess you should be using `this.router.navigate(['detail']);`

Comment: But I need to open a new popup window with the router state. Can I do the same with the above?

Comment: you need to make use of modal . do you have a plunker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `window.open` to navigate in SPA.

```
this.router.navigate(['detail'])
//OR
this.router.navigateByUrl('/detail')
```

Why you want to move user away from screen? You either navigate user to `detail`  page directly or open modal window.

If you still want to move user to next window you could use

```
window.open('/detail', '_blank')
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, how can I get a popup window to open with the above? It is not clear to me if that is possible. Please see my onRowClick above in the MasterComponent

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a modal "pop-up" try implementing a Bootstrap modal... link below.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: Thanks a link Ben!